# Django Rest Framework Email Validation invalid

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework, put

I want to update a "employee" instance by sending PUT requests to Django Rest Framework.
The Put requests fail due to failed email validation.

model.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    Employees_id = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
    Employees_acn = models.CharField('Mitarbeiternummer', max_length=10)
    Employees_first = models.CharField('Vorname', max_length=200)
    Employees_last = models.CharField('Nachname', max_length=200)
    Employees_mail = models.EmailField('E-Mail', null=True, blank=True)
    Employees_deleted = models.BooleanField('Gelöscht', default=False)
```

serializer.py:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class Employee(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,BelongsToClient]
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            employee = EmployeeModel.objects.filter(Employees_deleted= False).get(pk=pk)
        except EmployeeModel.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status = 404)
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employee, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        print(serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The failure doesn't depend on which email address I enter. All request I've tried failed.
This is the error message (serializer.errors):

```
{'Employees_mail': [ErrorDetail(string='Enter a valid email address.', code='invalid')]}
```

I have no validation in my serializers class. Why do I get this validation error? Do I have to make any settings?

Comment: _I have no validation in my serializers class_ I assume you're inheriting the default validation for each field.